# It is not inserting data but it says "yes"

Tags: php, sql

I tried this code

```
<?
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '123');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
if(isset($_POST['Murad'])){
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link,'websiteusers' );
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$userName=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['pwd1'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

$sqlb = "INSERT INTO websiteusers (fullname,lastname,userName,password,email)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$userName', '$password', '$email')";
if(mysqli_query($link,$sqlb)){
            echo "no";
}else {
    echo "yes";
}
 mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

But it is not inserting data but echos "yes".
Why it is not inserting i have checked all input names and column names it is not wrong

Comment: Instead of `echo "yes"`, do `echo mysqli_error($link)` and copy the result here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the expected behaviour. Your `if-else statement` looks like:

```
if(mysqli_query($link,$sqlb)) {
// display "no" if query is executed successfully
} else {
// display "yes" if query is not executed successfully
}
```

`mysqli_query()` will return `false` on failure, otherwise it will return `mysqli_result object` or `true` on success.

So, just swap the positions of "yes" and "no" and if you're still wondering why it's not working, use the following line in your `else statement`:

```
echo mysqli_error($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it echoes "yes", then it is expected that it does not insert the data, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepeared Statements, you avoid SQL Injections and it's easier to maintain the code if you change your database...

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "websiteusers";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$query = "INSERT INTO websiteusers (fullname, lastname, userName, password, email)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $fullname, $lastname, $username, $password, $email);

// set parameters and execute
$fullname ="Donald Duck";
$lastname = "Duck";
$username = "donalod";
$password = sha1("DonaldDuck1!");
$mail = "donald@duck.com"
$stmt->execute();

$fullname ="Mickey Mouse";
$lastname = "Mouse";
$username = "mickey";
$password = sha1("IloveDaisy");
$mail = "mickey@mouse.org"
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

This example is copied from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) and edited for your benefits.

More information about prepeared Statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

Trying this:

```
if(mysqli_query($link,$sqlb) === FALSE){
    echo mysqli_error($link);
}else {
    echo "yes";
}
```